# Do i really need another framework for android game programming

Tags: android

I recently started with android game programming. I feel OK to work with OpenGL java. I can develop games without using other frameworks like unity3d and many others.

I feel if i start to use any framework it will make my work fast. But when come to performance i discovered that the frameworks burn out resources ....

**Do I really need to choose any framework for android game development? If yes what will be the best bet (best in free & best paid)**

Thanks alot for reading out and responding

Comment: Probably better asked on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Create your own framework. This will cost nothing and you will have full control and ability to modify and enhance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Engines and frameworks to create games for Android:

- **Unity 3D Android / IOS (300$)** (nice if you can afford it) EDIT: It's for free now :).
- AndEngine http://www.andengine.org/blog/
- **LibGDX http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/** <-- I prefer this one
- angle http://code.google.com/p/angle/
- Rokon http://www.rokonandroid.com/
- SHIVA http://www.stonetrip.com/

You don't have to choose a framework. But it's hard work to create a game for android. When you want to write a 3D game I hope you know what you're doing. It's almost impossible to write high quality 3D games by yourself (enjoy drawing 3D models and optimizing your code.). Thats why I stay with 2D for now.

Comment: for your Information, Unity3D for Android is now available for free!